# React Native Camera

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install, react-native-ios

**Hey there!**

So, I'm testing React-Native and this problem have come up, and not sure what it wants.

I have upgraded it, and also download latest versions.

This is the error:

> npm WARN react-native-camera@0.6.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0
>   but none was installed.

It won't allow me to download it running the following command

```
npm install react-native-camera --save
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have react installed with a version higher than 15.4.0?

Comment: the question what is your RN version.

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.43.3

Comment: this RN camera has a lot of open issues. I tried it and abandoned. Have you checked out react-native-viro? I came across it, but didn't have time to look into it much. Took another route

Answer (score 1):

Hey i had the same problem with react native camera

First make sure the version is up to date.Either latest or next. Unless update it
as

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Then reinstall camera again(No need to uninstall anything, because it is not installed yet)

Here is the same issue that i opened in [github](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/661#issuecomment-292893591) now Closed because it solved the problem :)

**EDIT:**

i'm sure you got this error when you start to run

```
npm install react-native-camera@https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git --save
```

command right ? so it failed and never installed so,
what you have to do is run command

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

then run

```
npm install react-native-camera@https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git --save
```

back again

Comment: Hey, thanks for reaching out! I did do this and to tried again just to clarify, however, still the same old message. I wonder what I might be doing wrong... Cheers

Comment: Hi mate, I tried the following solution but still no luck. I will try to experiment and will see if it works out :)) Thanks for your time man!  (Will report back when fixed)